# How to send http request to a php file and get the result?

Tags: java, php, android, apache, http

I want to send a `http` request to a `php` file that is stored in my pc. With the request I want to pass a `string` as a parameter that will be used as a `variable` in the `php` file. Finally I want to get the `result` generated in the php file into my `activity java class`. What can I do to send a `http` request to achieve my requirements?

**RegVerificationActivity:**

```
public class RegVerificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText var_id, ser_num;
    private Button next;

    private String ID, S_num;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg_verification);

        var_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v_id);
        ser_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ser_num);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ID = var_id.getText().toString().trim();
                S_num = ser_num.getText().toString().trim();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `volley`,`retrofit` or `OkHttpClient ` for sending data to php and receiving response back .

Comment: Thank you very much. Got it working with volley. Thanks a lot. @Swati